# Is there a way to solve this type of diffrential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

While doing a derivation  I ran into the problem of finding a solution of $|\frac{d}{dt}\vec{r(t)}|=c$  where $\vec{r(t)}$ is position vector of a particle in space and $c$ is a constant.

Being a non mathematics major, I am unfamiliar with this sort of differential equations. What is the proper name for such differential equations and how can I solve this particular example?

Comment: This is (almost) a so-called natural parametrization of a curve defined by $\vec r = \vec r(t)$. So, in fact, it can be almost everything.

Comment: You're working within a 3d space?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes

Comment: @zhoraster I would love to see two solutions satisfying it.

Comment: In that case, as said zhoraster, your particle has a constant speed, but the trajectory can be any smooth curve.

Comment: OK,I get it. Would I get the same result if I work in 2D?

Comment: Yes, all the same.